# Word Counter in App script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to be able to type words and have the word count show with a count down from a goal of words, like when typing 50,000 word goal, and then be able to show an average word count needed over 30 days to reach 50,000. Is there a script function that would allow me to get the number of words in a document? I could then assign the word count to a variable and work from there.

Comment: There have been [several past questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+count+words) about word-counting scripts. One of those should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Example of a simple count :

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var count = body.getText().split(/[ ,]+/).length;
  Logger.log(count)
}
```